# How to make dart Widgets fully transparent to see platform native view under FlutterView?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a video chat app, using some platform native SDK like WebRTC to implement the video part, using flutter to implement other interactivity, how could I achieve that?

In Android, I try to hook the `createFlutterView` method, create a `FrameLayout` to hold the `FlutterView` and other native views under `FlutterView`, and make it as Activity's content view by `setContentView`.

`FlutterView` is a subclass of `SurfaceView`, so I can make it transparent like this:

```
flutterView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
flutterView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

To make `FlutterView`'s surface background transparent, I declare `android:colorBackground` as `#00000000` in my theme, according to [`FlutterView`'s source code](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/shell/platform/android/io/flutter/view/FlutterView.java#L146).

With those setup, I can see the view under `FlutterView` for a short period, after that it's covered by Widgets declared in dart code. I think that short period is the dart code load time.

To verify that, I create a pure Android project with the same views as above, but without any dart code. In that project, views under `FlutterView` show well all the time.

So, my question is, how to make dart Widgets fully transparent to see platform native view under FlutterView?

Comment: Did you see this example in the main flutter repo? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/platform_view

Comment: @JonahWilliams Of course I see it, but it's another totally different thing, it just launch another Activity and keep counter state.

Comment: If you have an Android demonstration, post it to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues